# unable execute arm-cc on docker images ( ubuntu 12.04 base )

Tags: c, linux, gcc, docker

i want execute arm-cc binary on docker images (ubuntu 12.04 base)
but can't

the process was below ...

1. download arm CC using wget ( https://launchpad.net/linaro-toolchain-binaries/trunk/2013.10/+download/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2013.10_linux.tar.xz )
2. uncompress the file
3. execute arm cc (arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc)

   arm cc file is symbolic link

   arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -> arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8.2

and error occurred ...

gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2013.10_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: Command not found

what should I do ?

Docker file contents is below

## Ubuntu as base image

FROM ubuntu:12.04

MAINTAINER ...

## update ubuntu image

RUN apt-get update

## install essential package

RUN apt-get -y install vim

RUN apt-get -y install wget

RUN apt-get -y install bzip2

RUN apt-get -y install git

RUN apt-get -y install patch

RUN apt-get -y install make

RUN apt-get -y install kernel-package libncurses5-dev fakeroot wget bzip2 build-essential udev

## set environment variable so I know I'm in a container

ENV ARM_CROSS_COMPILER TRUE

## End Dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED

my machine is 64-bit and armcc executable is 32-bit.

when i was execute it on native linux, not occurs problem.

but on docker, error occurred. i tried 64-bit compiler execution, well

running.